# Appbarlayout scroll behaviour with nestedscrolllayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

So I have this weird problem with **NestedScrollLayout** and **AppbarLayout**. My **NestedScrollLayout** has three **recyclerviews** which can be scrolled horizontally and **AppbarLayout** has toolbar which collapses when scrolling vertically everything works fine except when I start scrolling horizontally on **recyclerview** and without releasing my finger I start scrolling vertically **AppbarLayout** doesn't collapse but **NestedScrollLayout** scrolls.

here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar”
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_small”
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    </RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/child”
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior”>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label_a”
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=“label a”
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recycler1_holder”
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_journal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler1”
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_journal" />
                </RelativeLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler1_holder" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recycler2_holder”
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler2”
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

                </RelativeLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler2_holder" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recycler3_holder”
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler3”
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

                </RelativeLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler3_holder" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recycler4_holder”
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler4”
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please provide some code, I know that you described your scenario in the question, but without the code, some detail that you think that is unnecessary could be necessary for someone else. For example, I want to know if you are using CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: i think you have to set snap flag to your layout.

Comment: @kosas Also Screen short.

Comment: @DeepNaik snap flag just snaps it while scrolling, but I will try it

Comment: @jonathanrz added code sample to make things more clear

Comment: @DeepNaik snap doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I have an idea I can disable vertical scrolling on recycler views but not sure if its good practice

Comment: So if I set on recycler view android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" it fixes this problem, but scrolling becomes buggy its hard to change scrolling direction for example when I scroll horizontally releasing my finger and start scrolling vertically it still tries to scroll horizontally and I need to make it accurate to start scrolling vertically